# how to write a string message in a ROS bag file in C++

Tags: c++, ros

I'm pretty sure this basic question has already an answer somewhere but unfortunately I cannot find it.

For now, I have the following (which does not compile):

```
rosbag::Bag my_bag;
my_bag.write("/test_topic", timestamp, "str")
// write() expects a message type, as a std_msgs::String
```

I guess I have to write it as a message so, I tried to use a std_msgs::String
but I don't know how to use it and the [documentation](http://docs.ros.org/api/std_msgs/html/msg/String.html) is not so helpful with this topic.

I also tried to adapt the following Python code from [here](http://library.isr.ist.utl.pt/docs/roswiki/rosbag%282f%29Cookbook.html)

```
import rosbag

with rosbag.Bag('input.bag', 'a') as bag:
    from std_msgs.msg import String
    metadata = String(data='my metadata')

    for _, _, t in bag.read_messages():
        break
    bag.write('/metadata', metadata, t - roslib.rostime.Duration(0, 1))
```

I'm using ROS Groovy if it matters

Thanks in advance

Comment: When you say "does not work", what do you mean by that? Do you get build errors? Runtime errors (or crashes)? Unexpected results? Something else? Please elaborate (by *editing your question*).

Comment: done, thanks for your comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just had to build a ROS string message.

Here's the code:

```
rosbag::Bag my_bag;
std_msgs::String str_message;
str_message.data = "message content";
my_bag.write("/test_topic", timestamp, str_message);
```

Comment: What timestamp did you use? Now?

Comment: Sorry I didn't see your comment, I don't have access to the code anymore nor remember what timestamp I was using